# Tomcat ROOT.xml

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a WAR as the root application on a Tomcat server. I can manage to do it by adding a line  in the server.xml configuration file, but I'd like to externalize that from the server configuration. Note that I also should not modify the WAR in any way.

Documentation seems to indicate that I should be able to do that by adding a ROOT.xml file in ${CATALINA_HOME}/[Engine]/[hostname]/. I tried with the following content :

```
<Context docBase="webappname" path="" />
```

but it is not working (I still see the defaut Tomcat webpage).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Tomcat Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F), you must place your war file **outside** of `webapps` to prevent double deployment. The `docBase` pointing to the full path of your WAR file, something like this:

```
# ls -l /opt/tomcat6/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    19962865 Aug 19 10:56 cas.war

# cat conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml 
<Context docBase="/opt/tomcat6/cas.war" path="" />
```